# Navigation Drawer does not remember selection & transition issues

Tags: android

so I'm having an issue with the NavigationDrawer I've implemented in my app. What I've done is extending the NavigationDrawer activity to my other activities and it works fine.

What I intend for it to do is to open a new Activity on clicking the link in the drawer, but two things that I don't want to happen happen:

1. The navigation drawer will start to close, and this will be cut off with the new activity starting, with the activity on screen collapsing into the background and the new one sliding from below. How do I get it to transit properly, like when the drawer closes the screen will flash before the new Activity's information shows up?
2. The selection on the Navigation Drawer will be incorrect, eg. when I am on the "News Feed" page and select "High Scores", the activity switches, but the selection will stay on "News Feed". How can I switch the selection with the page switching?

navigationDrawerActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class navigationDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
protected DrawerLayout fullLayout;
protected FrameLayout actContent;
private Toolbar mToolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(final int layoutResID) {

    fullLayout = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer, null);
    actContent = (FrameLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.act_content);

    // This code combines this activity along with others for the NavigationDrawer to be global
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, actContent, true);
    super.setContentView(fullLayout);

    //NavigationDrawer settings
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setNavigationViewListener();

}

//Enables the NavDrawer icon to work
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//Handles navigation view item clicks
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.nav_newsFeed: {
            Intent intent = new Intent (this, newsfeedActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            break;
        }

        case R.id.nav_hiScores: {
            Intent intent = new Intent (this, hiscoresActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            break;
        }
    }

    //close navigation drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void setNavigationViewListener() {
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }
}
```

EDIT:

So I managed to solved the problem after tweaking around with the code a bit, and essentially I added an onResume to each of my activities. Within that onResume it sets the item selected in the navigationview, as well as using overridePendingTransition to stop that transition problem i was having.

Answer (score 0):

In activity, which display high score do that in onCreate():

```
navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_hiScores);
```

**P.S.**

Navigation drawer should be used to change fragments in single activity. Do not use it to switch between multiple activities.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I've tried what you suggested and the app crashed on start... Tried to put it under the cases in onNavigationItemSelected and the app crashed on tapping the link.. any suggestions?

As for the fragmentation part I've read up on it but I didn't use it, might try it out later

Comment: @bayobayo what logCat says?

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to change Activites with NavigationView or NavigationDrawer but to set selected position for your navigation inside current activity you can send int data with the intent you start activity with and set checked item with that index.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I&#39;ve tried this just now but the app crashed on tapping the link lol

Comment: If you do that right it should not crash. You send the exact position of currently selected item on navigation drawer with intent and on new actvities navigation drawer you set checked item to that index. It's not that complex you should check your logcat why it crashes. It does not crash for sending data with intent or setting checked position of not null navigation drawer or navigation view.